# find out the error in this code

Tags: php

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    UserName <input type="text" name="user"><br>

    PassWord <input type="password" name="pwd"><br>

    <input type="submit" name="login" value="LogIn">
    <?php login(); ?>
</form>
```

this code will give an error that

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function login() in
>   /var/www/trainees/bhupender/cms/admin.php on line 10.

this my function.php files coding

function login() {

```
if(!isset($_POST['username']))
    return;

global $link;
$query = "SELECT * from `b_user` where username = '{$_POST['username']}' AND password = '{$_POST['password']}'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$no_of_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo $no_of_results;
if($no_of_results === 1){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
        header('location: manage.php');
        exit;
} else {
    header('location: index.php');
        exit;
}
```

}

Comment: undefined function login() , so where's your login() function?

Comment: You are trying to call a function login, which doesn't excists?

Comment: is `function login()` exist in your code ?

Comment: you can not do like this... either use AJAX or validate after submit...

Comment: function login(){
global $link;
$query= "SElect * from `b_user`";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
 $all_pages = array();
 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
  $all_pages[] = $row;
  }
  if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
        if(($_POST['user']=="$v[username]")&&($_POST['pwd']=="$v[password]"))
        {
         include('manage.php');
      
        }
         else{
          die('unauthorized user.');
         }
         }
}

Comment: what are the steps that are to be followed whilt submitting a form with ajax

Comment: yes function.php exist in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use

```
    <?php
     function login() {
    //function body
}
     if($_POST) {
       login();
    }
    ?>
```

And your html;

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    UserName <input type="text" name="user"><br>

    PassWord <input type="password" name="pwd"><br>

    <input type="submit" name="login" value="LogIn">
</form>
```